# how to mirror directory with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to mirror directory with htaccess?

For example:

```
/folder1 <= is empty
/folder2/blah/blah <= here is content
```

I want `folder1` to display `folder2` contents. So that when you go to `folder1/` you can navigate to `folder1/blah/blah/files`

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) can do this, although `folder1` shouldn't exist for it to work:

```
Alias /folder1 /folder2/blah/blah
```

- In `.htaccess` files, you can only Alias to a directory inside the web root.
- It doesn't always work in `.htaccess` files, depending on the server configuration.
- In the central configuration, you may have to use an absolute path as the Alias target.

Comment: Hi, Where do I have to add the Alias? do I need to restart Apache or server after that? I have the mod installed on the server.